# How to set exact coordinates in a PNG image?

Tags: linux, png, qr-code, libpng

Platform: Linux
Tool: Qrencode (Open source application for creating QR code in linux)

I am using this qrencode application to generate QR code. The output file format that I am using is PNG. But when I try to print the PNG file using dot-matrix printer, it prints correctly but scrolls down whole page i.e. it occupies the whole page, but my requirement is that I should be able to print the image to any point of an page.

Unfortunately I don't have time to go through the entire source code of LIBPNG and QRENCODE.

Comment: how do you print the `png` files ?

Comment: using the 'lpr' command

Comment: Do your PNG images contain offset information?  Use "pngcheck -v file.png" to find out if there is an "oFFs" chunk or "vpAg" chunk present.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to check the [man](http://www.it.uu.se/datordrift/maskinpark/skrivare/cups/) page for `lpr`

It has an option for positioning the image on the page, e.g. `-o position=name`.
Check the possible position names in the manual.

Most probably you would need to scale your images.
Be sure that your image is not too large for fitting in the page.

Comment: I tried the options in lpr -o but after printing the QR code loses its data. If possible can you please tell me the syntax for that

Comment: what do you mean by loosing it's data  ? Please provide full examples of what you've tried.

Comment: "lpr -o position=center myimage {center,top,left,right,top-left,top-right, bottom,bottom-left,bottom-right}"  This prints the image at the center top bottom left right but it does not serve my purpose as i want to print the image at any random position of the page. The link which i went through is          https://cs.brown.edu/about/system/services/printing/linux-tips/

Comment: Also another problem that i am facing is that the print scrolls to the next page after printing the image. I tried to disable form feed but it did not work. The link that i went through is http://www.ahinc.com/support/linux-101/printing/ , i tried the sf option. Can you please help me with this also??

Comment: are you sure that your `png` files are not large enough ?

Comment: The png files are very small, actually it contains only a QR code

Comment: Having printed it the `png` to an arbitrary position with `lpr` looks is not possible.

Comment: is there any particular format that you would suggest??

Comment: I would suggest to generate your `png`s to conform with the page format e.g. A4 paper format, where the image will be a fully transparent image with the `png` positioned at a place where you want.